What letter of the korean alphabet is closest to representing an open mid back rounded vowel? ɔ
What letter of the korean alphabet is closest to representing an open mid back rounded vowel?The open mid back rounded vowel is written as ɔ in the international phonetic alphabet.
Feel free to edit this post if there is a mistake in the korean words shown in the table below.



StandardEnglishSpelling
CommonMisspellingWrittenbyAmericanChildren
StandardInternationalPhoneticNotation
Korean




thoughtTHOUGHT
th-aw-t
/θɔt/
생각하다


lawnLAWN
l-aw-n
/lɔn/
잔디


awningAWNING
aw-n-ee-ng
/ɔnɪŋ/
천막지붕


awfulAWFUL
aw-f-uh-l
/ɔːfəl/
추악한


fawnFAWN
f-aw-n
/fɔn/
엷은 황갈색사슴어린 사슴




What letter of the korean alphabet is closest to representing the AW in the English word for fawn and the English word for lawn?

This sound of English words such as THOUGHT is typically approximated as ㅗ, e.g. in 소스 (soseu) ‘sauce’ or ‘source’, 소시지 (sosiji) ‘sausage’, or 옥션 (oksyeon) ‘auction’.
The sign ㅗ is, however, also used to approximate the vowel of English words such as GOAT, e.g. in 소파 (sopa) ‘sofa’ or 도넛 (doneot) ‘donut’ or, sometimes, the vowel of English words such as LOT, e.g. in 옵션 (opsyeon) ‘option’ or 조깅 (joging) ‘jogging’.
